# Custom PMD rulset file on Jenkins Ant build not working

Tags: java, xml, jenkins, ant, pmd

Here's how I am trying to load and reference the ruleset.xml file,

```
<property name="xms3k-build.pmd.rule.url" value="${xms3k-build.url}/${xms3k-build.version}/ruleset.xml" />

<property name="xms3k-build.pmd.rule.file" value="${xms3k-build.dir}/ruleset.xml" />

<!-- PMD static analysis task.             -->
    <target name="pmd" depends="compile, init-pmd">
        <path id="pmd.aux.classpath">
                <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/${ivy.conf.test}"/>
        </path>
                <pmd rulesetfiles="xms3k-build.pmd.rule.file" >
                <formatter type="xml" toFile="pmd_report.xml" />
            <fileset dir="${source.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${source-test.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </pmd>
```

The following error occurred while executing this line:

```
common.xml:481: Can't find resource 'null' for rule 'xms3k-build.pmd.rule.file'. 

Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL and is on the CLASSPATH. Here's the current classpath: /usr/share/java/ant.jar:/usr/share/java/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/java/jaxp_parser_impl.jar:/usr/share/java/xml-commons-apis.jar:/usr/share/java/junit.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/java/junit.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-junit4.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/tools.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar
```

I have tried many variants of the style.xml file. Here is what I am currently trying:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
       xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">
     <description>
     This ruleset checks my code for bad stuff
  </description>
  <rule ref="rulesets/strings.xml"/>

</ruleset>
```

Comment: Have you tried running ant script using `-debug` option to see more details?

Comment: As "ms3k-build.pmd.rule.file" is a property, I'd try to use it like this: `<pmd rulesetfiles="${xms3k-build.pmd.rule.file}" >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adangel has posted in a comment the answer lied in a typo,

As "ms3k-build.pmd.rule.file" is a property, I'd try to use it like this: `<pmd rulesetfiles="${xms3k-build.pmd.rule.file}" >` – adangel